# Send e-mail if conditions are met, then sleep for one hour

Tags: python, email, sleep, wait

I have a script that sends me an e-mail if I ever see a number increase on a policy map on a network device.

This works well for me. But I now need it to e-mail me when it sees an exceed (no problem, can run a cron job every minute) -- but when it does see an exceed, I need the script to not run for an hour after so that I won't get flooded with mails. So what I'd like is for the script to go and check the network device every minute or so, but then whenever it does see an exceed, to stop running.

Can't think off the top of my (beginner's) head how to go about this.

My code pulls the stats off the network device via pexpect and dumps it into 1.txt. I then strip out what I need via regex and then compare to the previous run. It's not elegant, I know, but I'm a beginner...

I've removed a bunch of the code but here's the crux of it. 2.txt and 3.txt contain numbers - if the new number is higher, it emails me.

```
getexceeds = open("1.txt", "r").readlines()[12]
output = re.findall(r"\d+", getexceeds)[1]
with open("2.txt", "w") as outp:
    outp.write(output)

newnumber = open("2.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
oldnumber = open("3.txt", "r").readlines()[0]

if oldnumber < newnumber:
    send_email()
else:
    print "same"

src_file = "2.txt"
dst_file = "3.txt"
shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)
```

Thanks for any help here, I'm still getting my head around scripting and appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Would it be possible to get the time in python in seconds (timestamp format) and then simply work out that there are 3600 seconds in an hour, and when the time since the last email was sent is over that, send it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use the time library.  Which allows you to do lots of different things with time, such as:

```
time.sleep(secs)
```

An article on this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) (well, a few sentences) but in essence it just pauses the program for the given number of seconds.    Considering there are 3600 seconds in an hour just do:

```
time.sleep(3600)
```

Note:  This pauses the program for 60 minutes, which means that you will not be able to run any code during this time.

Comment: thanks for this. i should use my head. so i put the script in a simple while true loop, then added that time.sleep statement after the send e-mail statement... and it's perfect. thanks mate.

Comment: @captainyossarian No problem!  Exactly what this website is for =)